# Why does this css rule for a child element take precedence over its parent element

Tags: html, css

I have learnt that precedence of a CSS rule depends only on two factors

*Source: [freeCodeCamp youtube](https://youtu.be/zJSY8tbf_ys) @ **13:57:43***

1. Location
2. Specificity

The specificity can be calculated as follows:

number of *id* selectors = x
number of *class* selectors = y
number of *tag* selectors = z
*total* specificity = xyz

For the given HTML body

```
<div class="main-container">
  <p class="main-text" id="first-paragraph">First para of doc</p>
  <p class="main-text" id="first-paragraph">Second para of doc</p>
</div>
```

Example RULE-1
`.main-container .main-text { }`
has **specificty = 020**

Example RULE-2
`.main-text { }`
has **specificity = 010**

Thus, the ***first rule takes precedence*** despite its location

---

Example RULE-3
`.main-text { }`

Example RULE-4
`.main-container { }`

**My Question** Why does Rule-3 take precedence over Rule-4 ? Since when both of them have **specificity = 010**, *precedence should be based on their location* in the css document.

What's the explanation for the above? Is there any additional criteria for determining precedence or is the described precedence method not applicable for such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules apply to the element that is selected.

`.main-text { }` takes "precedence" over `.main-container { }` because `<p class="main-text" id="first-paragraph">` isn't matched by `.main-container { }` at all.

A style applying to `<div class="main-container">` would only influence `<p class="main-text" id="first-paragraph">` if the latter had a rule which was derived from a rule applied to the former (such as

- `border: inherit` which would explicitly copy the `border` rules into the child element
- `width: 50%` which would set the width of the child element to be half the width of the parent
- `background-color: transparent` which would set the background colour of the child so you could see the background colour of the parent through it